# Move Anchor tag to centre of navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the Anchor tags in the navigation to the center of the bar, How can I make it that the Anchors will remain fixed and not change position in different screens? My code is below:

**HTML CODE**

```
<nav class = "nav-main" id = "navMain">

            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href = "#" class = "nav-item"> HOME</a>                              
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">ABOUT US </a>
                </li>

                 <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">PORTFOLIO </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">SERVICES </a>
                </li>
                  <li>
                   <a href = "#" class = "nav-item">CONTACT US </a>
                </li>

          </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
    .nav-main {
    width:100%;
    background-color: #222;
    height:70px;
    color:#fff;
}




.nav-main .logo{
  float:left;
    height:40px;
    padding:15px 30px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 40px;
}


.nav-main > ul {

    margin:0;
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {

    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.nav-main > ul > li > a {

    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left:100px;
}


    .nav-item {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 20px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

.nav-item:hover {

    background-color:forestgreen;

}
```

**JS FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/x45wqktz/

I used text-align : center but no result. Right its on the left side of the bar.

Comment: the text is already centered, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `nav-main` class this property:

```css
.nav-main {
   width:100%;
   background-color: #222;
   height:70px;
   color:#fff;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text seems to be centered already. The only way the text is not centered is if you make the window size very small, which then on you have to create the navbar to be responsive. I'd read more about @media tag: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp